# get unique values of single column in list of data frames in R

Tags: r, lapply, purrr

I have a list of dataframes and want all unique values of `a` across them

```
dd <- list()
dd$data <- list(one = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3)),
           two = data.frame(a = c(1,2,4)))
```

```
$data
$data$one
  a
1 1
2 2
3 3

$data$two
  a
1 1
2 2
3 4
```

And I'd like to return

```
1 2 3 4
```

I know I can bind the two dataframes together then look for unique values but in my actual dataset the list of dataframes are different sizes with different columns, only `a` being the same so I don't think this is the most computationally elegant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `unlist` the data.frames and get the `unique` elements

```
unique(unlist(dd$data))
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

If we need to extract only 'a' column

```
unique(unlist(lapply(dd$data, `[[`, "a")))
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

---

Or with `map/pluck`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(dd$data,  pluck, "a") %>%
    flatten_dbl %>%
    unique
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Ah that's perfect - I didn't want to unlist because my actual data has a lot of columns! Thank you!